# Cauchy's inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

> Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be two sets of complex numbers. Prove Cauchy's inequality
>   $$\left| \sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i\right|^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^N |a_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^N |b_i|^2.$$
>   [*Hint:* Consider the sum $\sum_{i=1}^N \left| a_i - \lambda \bar b_i \right|^2$, and choose $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i \big/ \sum_{i=1}^N |b_i|^2$. Alternatively, give a proof by induction.]
>
> ---
>
> *Solution: The statement is obviously true for $\sum_{i=1}^N |b_i|^2 =0$, so we may assume $\sum_{i=1}^N |b_i|^2 \ne 0$. We have, for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$,
>   $$0 \le \sum_{i=1}^N \left|a_i - \lambda \bar b_i \right|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N |a_i|^2 + |\lambda|^2 \sum_{i=1}^N |b_i|^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re} \left(\bar\lambda \sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i \right).$$
>   Taking $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i \big/ \sum_{i=1}^N |b_i|^2$ produces the required inequality.*

I am having trouble seeing how the detail works. For example, what is $\lambda \bar b_i$? What is the last term $2\operatorname{Re}()$? Can some one show me the detailed work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It uses the fact that $|x-y|^2 = |x|^2+|y|^2-2 \operatorname{re} (x \overline{y})$. Let $x=a_i, y=\lambda \overline{b}_i$.

Comment: You're much much better off, given the outline, to work out the detail yourself. Your understanding will then be greater and will make it easier for you to apply the inequality successfully.

Comment: This & other similar proofs tend to obscure what's really going on, look up the paper "When Holder Met Minkowski" by Woeginger to see how easy & geometrically obvious this statement (& it's generalizations) are.

Comment: For anyone searching for the paper @bolbteppa suggests, the exact name is "When Cauchy and Hölder Met Minkowski: A Tour through Well-Known Inequalities"

Comment: @bolbteppa thx for suggestion~

Comment: @dfeuerthxs for editing~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\lambda$ is any complex value at the beginning that will later be assigned.

First note that $|a_i-\lambda\bar{b}_i|^2=|a_i|^2+|\lambda|^2|b_i|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\bar{\lambda} a_ib_i)$.

Recall, for a comple number $z$, we have $|z|^2=z\cdot \bar{z}$, so try to write out what above should be. At one point you will need to use the fact that for any complex number $z$ you have $z+\bar{z}=2\operatorname{Re}(z)$.

Hence, you have
\begin{align*}
0\leq \sum |a_i-\lambda\bar{b}_i|^2&=\sum (|a_i|^2+|\lambda|^2|b_i|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\bar{\lambda} a_ib_i)) \\ &=\sum|a_i|^2+|\lambda|^2\sum|b_i|^2-2\operatorname{Re}\left(\bar{\lambda}\sum a_ib_i\right)
\end{align*}
The last equality is because you can distribute the sum. Substituting for the desired $\lambda=\sum a_ib_i \big/\sum|b_i|^2$:
\begin{align*}
&=\sum|a_i|^2+ \left|\frac{\sum a_ib_i}{\sum|b_i|^2}\right|^2\sum|b_i|^2-2\operatorname{Re}\left(\overline{\sum a_ib_i\big/\sum|b_i|^2}\sum a_ib_i\right)\\
&=\sum|a_i|^2+\frac{\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2}{\sum|b_i|^2}-2\operatorname{Re} \left(\frac{|\sum a_ib_i|^2}{\sum|b_i|^2}\right).
\end{align*}
In the last equality I used $(\sum a_ib_i)\overline{\sum a_ib_i}=\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2$. Also, note that the value inside the $\operatorname{Re}$ is a real number hence:
\begin{align*}
&=\sum|a_i|^2+\frac{\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2}{\sum|b_i|^2}-2\frac{\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2}{\sum|b_i|^2} \\
&=\sum|a_i|^2-\frac{\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2}{\sum|b_i|^2}
\end{align*}
In total we have:
$$
0\leq \sum|a_i|^2-\frac{\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2}{\sum|b_i|^2}
$$Multiply by $\sum|b_i|^2$ to get: 
$$
0\leq \sum|a_i|^2\sum|b_i|^2-\left|\sum a_ib_i\right|^2
$$and you can finish off the details from here :-)